# Marshal and unmarshal JSON bodies without touching all fields

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I'm looking for a way to unmarshal a JSON body without having to specify targets for all fields. And then be a able to "remarshal" the body with implicit fields untouched.

Something like this would be good, but doesn't work as a expected: (https://play.golang.org/p/fnVOKrmiFj)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Transaction struct {
    Field1  string                  `json:"field1"`
    X       map[string]interface{}  `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
    body := []byte(`{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}`)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", string(body))

    var unmarshalledTransaction Transaction
    json.Unmarshal(body, &unmarshalledTransaction)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", unmarshalledTransaction)

    remarshalledTransaction, _ := json.Marshal(&unmarshalledTransaction)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", string(remarshalledTransaction))    
}
```

Gives the output

```
{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}
{Field1:value1 X:map[]}
{"field1":"value1"}
```

My expected result would be that `unmarshalledTransaction` contains the "leftover" fields in the `X` fields. And they are then restored when Marshalling again.

Can this be done?

Comment: You could Unmarshal to a `map[string]interface{}` then manually map whatever fields the struct actually has, removing them as you go. That would leave you with a map of the fields that were unmapped. Would that be of any use?

Comment: Possibly. Could you provide a working example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement the `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` interfaces, and write your own logic to remap the fields to the appropriate spots:

```
func (t *Transaction) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    data := t.X
    data["field1"] = t.Field1
    return json.Marshal(data)
}

func (t *Transaction) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
    t.Field1 = m["field1"].(string)
    delete(m, "field1")
    t.X = m
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KBGAsXB0xA

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned this in my original post, but in my real-world business scenario `field1` is of type `time.Time` and this now causes problems when unmarshalling. Do you know any way to get around this?

Comment: Marking this as accepted since it answers the original question in an elegant way. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding `Time`, I'm not too happy about having to parse the time a second time. I would much rather be able to use the implicit parsing inside the `json` library, where you don't have to specify a format string, for example. Since my data comes from multiple sources (MySQL and Postgres) with different formats on the time strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generic solution (that would work with any struct without knowing the fields in advance), you can implement a function that would un-marshal the body into a struct and also return the "leftover" fields.

For that you'd also need to implement a function that would convert any given struct to a map (to be used to then manipulate maps in a generic way instead of known-in-advance structs).

Like so:

```
func structToMap(object interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    tempJson, err := json.Marshal(object)
    if err != nil {
       return nil, err
    }
    var theMap map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(tempJson, &theMap)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return theMap, nil
}
```

And then:

```
func unmarshalWithLeftovers(jsonBody []byte, target interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBody, target)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    structMap, err := structToMap(target)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var leftOvers map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(jsonBody, &leftOvers)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for k, _ := range structMap {
        delete(leftOvers, k)
    }
    return leftOvers, nil
}
```

You can then combine the struct and the leftovers map in a similar fashion to re-marshal everything.

See here a working example with the same type and json string that you used in your question:

https://play.golang.org/p/Fot6YVurHH